# Problems to redirect the TObject.AfterConstruction to other procedure

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm trying to redirect the TObject.AfterConstruction to another procedure using the code bellow, but after a time a lot of exceptions start raise. Note: I use this kind of redirect to a lot of others solutions.

```
unit Unit109;

interface

uses
  Windows;

implementation

uses
  SyncObjs, SysUtils;

type
  PJump = ^TJump;
  TJump = packed record
    OpCode: Byte;
    Distance: Pointer;
  end;

  TObjectHack = class(TObject)
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction;
  end;

function GetMethodAddress(AStub: Pointer): Pointer;
const
  CALL_OPCODE = $E8;
begin
  if PBYTE(AStub)^ = CALL_OPCODE then
  begin
    Inc(Integer(AStub));
    Result := Pointer(Integer(AStub) + SizeOf(Pointer) + PInteger(AStub)^);
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

procedure AddressPatch(const ASource, ADestination: Pointer);
const
  JMP_OPCODE = $E9;
  SIZE = SizeOf(TJump);
var
  NewJump: PJump;
  OldProtect: Cardinal;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(ASource, SIZE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  begin
    NewJump := PJump(ASource);
    NewJump.OpCode := JMP_OPCODE;
    NewJump.Distance := Pointer(Integer(ADestination) - Integer(ASource) - 5);

    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, ASource, SizeOf(TJump));
    VirtualProtect(ASource, SIZE, OldProtect, @OldProtect);
  end;
end;

procedure OldAfterConstruction;
asm
  call TObject.AfterConstruction;
end;

{ TCriticalSectionHack }
procedure TObjectHack.AfterConstruction;
begin
end;

initialization
  AddressPatch(GetMethodAddress(@OldAfterConstruction), @TObjectHack.AfterConstruction);

end.
```

Maybe the AfterConstruction is stored in VMT (vmtAfterConstruction = -28) and it must by changed other way ? like:

```
PatchCodeDWORD(PDWORD(Integer(Self) + vmtAfterConstruction), DWORD(@TObjectHack.AfterConstruction));


procedure PatchCodeDWORD(ACode: PDWORD; AValue: DWORD);
var
  LRestoreProtection, LIgnore: DWORD;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(ACode, SizeOf(ACode^), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, LRestoreProtection) then
  begin
    ACode^ := AValue;
    VirtualProtect(ACode, SizeOf(ACode^), LRestoreProtection, LIgnore);
    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, ACode, SizeOf(ACode^));
  end;
end;
```

I tried the both ways, with no success, someone can give me a help ?

If some one would like to read about this kinds of approaches:

- http://hallvards.blogspot.com.br/2007/05/hack17-virtual-class-variables-part-i.html
- http://hallvards.blogspot.com.br/2006/03/hack-8-explicit-vmt-calls.html
- http://hallvards.blogspot.com.br/2007/03/hack14-changing-class-of-object-at-run.html

Tks

Comment: Currently in orbit round Neptune. Someone asked me how far I'd go to avoid doing something like this. However, what exceptions do you get a lot of?

Comment: Just some AVs, nothing that can help find the problem.
But, I'll put a stack trace on the application to check if I can identify the point where I get the error. I put the result the st here in a little while.

Comment: May I ask you, why ? Couldn't you just override it in a sub-class ?

Comment: @TLama, I have a LOT of third libs and it's not possible to recompile/change all of them. :/

Comment: No way, the Exception is not created correctly, so I can run into it stacktrace.
I'll try other things, any news I post here.

Comment: Duh, one problem I found, the size of TObject.AfterConstruction instructions is 0 bytes 'cause its empty. 
And the AddressPatch needs 5 bytes to hack the method (1 byte to jump opcode + 4 bytes to address).
I'm thinking about other way to hack it, if it works I post here.

Comment: You could obtain the address of System._AfterConstruction and hook that. But it would be very messy indeed. In your shoes I would be looking for an alternative. What's driving you to want to hook all calls to TObject.AfterConstruction?

Comment: @David Heffernan, I'd like to develop a third application to check the instances in my main application in runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED - Now working to increase and decrease the number of items. 
To make it work is just to put the unit as the first unit of your dpr.
Now, I'll just optimize some methods and put here the outputs I want. (I'll not reedit the post, not necessary)
But if you'd like to use, fell free to test and report bugs.
I put a **simple** out put if you'd like to test, the procedure *SaveInstancesToFile*, it creates a test.txt file in your application path with the output of counters.

```
unit ObjectCounter;

  {  Develop by rodrigofrezino@gmail.com
     Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/users/225010/saci
     Please, any bug let me know}

interface

  procedure SaveInstancesToFile;

implementation

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, TypInfo;

type

  PClassVars = ^TClassVars;
  TClassVars = class(TObject)
  private
    class var ListClassVars: TList;
  public
    InstanceCount: integer;
    BaseClassName: string;
    constructor Create;

    class procedure SaveToDisk;
  end;

  PJump = ^TJump;
  TJump = packed record
    OpCode: Byte;
    Distance: Pointer;
  end;

  TObjectHack = class(TObject)
  private
    class procedure SetClassVars(AClassVars: TClassVars);
    class function GetClassVars: TClassVars;

    procedure IncCounter;
    procedure DecCounter;
    procedure OldFreeInstace;
  public
    class function InitInstance(Instance: Pointer): TObject;
  end;

var
  FOldFreeInstance: Pointer;

procedure SaveInstancesToFile;
begin
  TClassVars.SaveToDisk;
end;

function GetMethodAddress(AStub: Pointer): Pointer;
const
  CALL_OPCODE = $E8;
begin
  if PBYTE(AStub)^ = CALL_OPCODE then
  begin
    Inc(Integer(AStub));
    Result := Pointer(Integer(AStub) + SizeOf(Pointer) + PInteger(AStub)^);
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

procedure AddressPatch(const ASource, ADestination: Pointer);
const
  JMP_OPCODE = $E9;
  SIZE = SizeOf(TJump);
var
  NewJump: PJump;
  OldProtect: Cardinal;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(ASource, SIZE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  begin
    NewJump := PJump(ASource);
    NewJump.OpCode := JMP_OPCODE;
    NewJump.Distance := Pointer(Integer(ADestination) - Integer(ASource) - 5);

    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, ASource, SizeOf(TJump));
    VirtualProtect(ASource, SIZE, OldProtect, @OldProtect);
  end;
end;

procedure PatchCodeDWORD(ACode: PDWORD; AValue: DWORD);
var
  LRestoreProtection, LIgnore: DWORD;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(ACode, SizeOf(ACode^), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, LRestoreProtection) then
  begin
    ACode^ := AValue;
    VirtualProtect(ACode, SizeOf(ACode^), LRestoreProtection, LIgnore);
    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, ACode, SizeOf(ACode^));
  end;
end;

procedure OldAfterConstruction;
asm
  call TObject.InitInstance;
end;

{ TCriticalSectionHack }
procedure TObjectHack.DecCounter;
begin
  if (Self.ClassType <> TClassVars) then
    Dec(GetClassVars.InstanceCount);
  OldFreeInstace;
end;

class function TObjectHack.GetClassVars: TClassVars;
begin
  Result := PClassVars(Integer(Self) + vmtAutoTable)^;
end;

class procedure TObjectHack.SetClassVars(AClassVars: TClassVars);
begin
  AClassVars.BaseClassName := Self.ClassName;
  PatchCodeDWORD(PDWORD(Integer(Self) + vmtAutoTable), DWORD(AClassVars));
end;

procedure RegisterClassVarsSupport(const Classes: array of TObjectHack);
var
  LClass: TObjectHack;
  LRestoreProtection: DWORD;
  LIgnore: DWORD;
  LVMT: Pointer;
begin
  for LClass in Classes do
    if LClass.GetClassVars = nil then
    begin
      LClass.SetClassVars(TClassVars.Create);

      //Change de mvt to object mvt
      LVMT := PPointer(Integer(TObject) + vmtFreeInstance)^;
      if VirtualProtect(LVMT, SizeOf(LVMT^), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, LRestoreProtection) then
      begin
        LVMT :=  @TObjectHack.DecCounter;
        VirtualProtect(LVMT, SizeOf(LVMT^), LRestoreProtection, LIgnore);
        FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, LVMT, SizeOf(LVMT^));
      end;
    end
    else
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Class %s has automated section or duplicated registration.', [LClass.ClassName]);
end;

procedure TObjectHack.IncCounter;
begin
  if (Self.ClassType = TClassVars) then
    Exit;

  if GetClassVars = nil then
    RegisterClassVarsSupport(Self);

  Inc(GetClassVars.InstanceCount);
end;

class function TObjectHack.InitInstance(Instance: Pointer): TObject;
asm
        PUSH    EBX
        PUSH    ESI
        PUSH    EDI
        MOV     EBX,EAX
        MOV     EDI,EDX
        STOSD
        MOV     ECX,[EBX].vmtInstanceSize
        XOR     EAX,EAX
        PUSH    ECX
        SHR     ECX,2
        DEC     ECX
        REP     STOSD
        POP     ECX
        AND     ECX,3
        REP     STOSB
        MOV     EAX,EDX
        MOV     EDX,ESP
@@0:    MOV     ECX,[EBX].vmtIntfTable
        TEST    ECX,ECX
        JE      @@1
        PUSH    ECX
@@1:    MOV     EBX,[EBX].vmtParent
        TEST    EBX,EBX
        JE      @@2
        MOV     EBX,[EBX]
        JMP     @@0
@@2:    CMP     ESP,EDX
        JE      @@5
@@3:    POP     EBX
        MOV     ECX,[EBX].TInterfaceTable.EntryCount
        ADD     EBX,4
@@4:    MOV     ESI,[EBX].TInterfaceEntry.VTable
        TEST    ESI,ESI
        JE      @@4a
        MOV     EDI,[EBX].TInterfaceEntry.IOffset
        MOV     [EAX+EDI],ESI
@@4a:   ADD     EBX,TYPE TInterfaceEntry
        DEC     ECX
        JNE     @@4
        CMP     ESP,EDX
        JNE     @@3
@@5:    MOV     EBX,EAX
        CALL    TObjectHack.IncCounter
        MOV     EAX,EBX
        POP     EDI
        POP     ESI
        POP     EBX
end;

procedure TObjectHack.OldFreeInstace;
asm
  call FOldFreeInstance;
end;

procedure InitFreeInstance;
begin
  FOldFreeInstance := PPointer(Integer(TObject) + vmtFreeInstance)^;
end;

{ TClassVars }

constructor TClassVars.Create;
begin
  ListClassVars.Add(Self);
end;

class procedure TClassVars.SaveToDisk;
var
  LStringList: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin                               
  LStringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    LStringList.Add('CLASS | NUMBER OF INSTANCES');
    for i := 0 to ListClassVars.Count -1 do
      LStringList.Add(TClassVars(ListClassVars.Items[I]).BaseClassName + '|' + IntToStr(TClassVars(ListClassVars.Items[I]).InstanceCount));

    LStringList.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'test.txt');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LStringList);
  end;
end;

initialization
  TClassVars.ListClassVars := TList.Create;
  InitFreeInstance;
  AddressPatch(GetMethodAddress(@OldAfterConstruction), @TObjectHack.InitInstance);

end.
```